# How to Temporarily Suspend Security Policy Checks / Or Temporarily Grant Root Access?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, root, policykit

**Note:** *Please feel free to edit the question -- I am having a hard time expressing it!*

## Question:

How do you impersonate a regular user--while still retaining admin/root privileges to execute any command on behalf of that target user?

**A Mechanism To:**

1. Allows Complete root/admin access to execute any command;
2. Allows you to specify some "Target Group";
3. Allow you to specify some "Target User";
4. And ensures that all commands, scripts, etc, are executed on behalf of that user/group -- setting the "Target User" and "Target Group" as owner ...

These examples show how `pkexec` and/or `sudo` have to be specified for each and every command -- which is what I am trying to avoid doing :

## pkexec:

FAIL: Requires admin to prefix with `sudo` and `pkexec`.

1. `sudo pkexec -u TestUser mkdir /home/TestUser/NewFolder`

   - Success: Creates folder and assigns correct permissions
2. `sudo pkexec -u btsync mkdir /opt/btsync`

   - **FAIL:** Does not work for service accounts without home folders: `Error changing to home directory /home/btsync: No such file or directory`

## sudo:

FAIL: Requires admin to prefix with `sudo`.

1 `sudo pkexec -u btsync mkdir /opt/btsync`

- **FAIL:** Makes Folder - But Assigns Root Owner.
- **FAIL:** Requires fixing permissions afterwards, increasing commands entered by x3 sometimes.

## Desired Functionally using BTSync as an Example:

- `root@localhost > enterElevatedShell -u btsync`
- `btsync@localhost > nano /etc/asound.conf`
- many commands entered manually.
- `btsync@localhost > exit`
- `root@localhost >`

**or:**

- `root@localhost > stopauthorizationModules`
- `root@localhost > sudo -i btsync`
- `btsync@localhost > nano /etc/asound.conf`
- many commands entered manually.
- `btsync@localhost > exit`
- `root@localhost >`

**or:**

- `root@localhost > sudo --setUmask=0222 --setTargetUser=btsync`
- `root@localhost > sudo -E mkdir /opt/btsync`

## Common Scenarios:

***Note:*** This is in the context of *manual* system administration.

With Root Access:

1. Create /home/[username]/Subfolder | w/[username] as owner
2. Create /opt/[serviceAccount]Service | w/[serviceAccount] as owener
3. Create/Modify /etc/service/[someconfig] | w /[serviceAccount] as owner

Generally, I execute many, many commands, and going back behind flipping permission bits is tedious, non-consistent, and a security vulnerability rising from admin forgetfulness, or type-os.

Comment: which service account do you have in mind? some of them require specific selinux contexts for their files hence the permission denied error. under root `sudo -u user mkdir folder` should work for normal users.

Comment: @Azad Thanks Azad. For example, I want to create a btsync service account, and then manually create a bunch of folders, configuration files, move the executable around, etc -- all while assigning the appropriate permissions without explicitly going back and doing so.

Answer (score 0):

To create a directory and immediately set the owner:

```
sudo install -d -o owner -g group -m 755 /path/to/dir
```

You need to use install for this if the parent directory is not writeable by "owner" as is the case for `/home`.

To create files simply use sudo

```
sudo -u owner touch /path/to/file
```

Or vi or whatever.

If you have a file you wish to copy and set the owner you can use install again. It works like cp with extra options

```
sudo install -o owner -g group -m 640 file /path/to/file
```

If you need to create a large number of files, users and directories etc. and you are worried about consistency perhaps you need too look at a configuration management system like puppet, chef, ansible or the like. It takes a bit more work to set up but it has the advantage that it can be reused.

Comment: Bram, Thanks. This does work, but even if it were to -- it would be incredibly tedious to use this to manually create many folders, copy files, etc, for common configuration tasks. `sudo -u btsync mkdir btsync` results in "cannot create directory 'btsync': permission denied.

Comment: I've updated my answer to address this. Mkdir requires write access to the parent dir.

Comment: - Bram.  Thanks again. `sudo pkexec -u TestUser mkdir /home/TestUser/NewFolder` does not require the parent folder to have write access.  -- But that still doesn't solve the problem eliminating the need of typing in "sudo" or "pkexec" for each and every command.